# How to send a counter via UART

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, uart, stm32cubeide

I have some problems with a program in which I want to send via UART a variable that is a counter.
The goal is to see this counter on Matlab Simulink.

Actually what I'm able to see on Matlab is not what i want to see, because I just see the values of the Characters in ASCII (I mean the characters of the printf...see the code then).

```
  while(1){

  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &bufferRX, 1);


    //Serial Stream Routine
    if(streamActive == 1 && counter < MAX_VALUE)    //RUNNING state: we start the counter and the transmission begin
    {
        if (dataReady == 1)

        {
            printf("The actual counter value is: %d \r\n", counter);

            counter++;

            dataReady = 0;
        }
    }
    else
        if(streamActive == 1 && counter >= MAX_VALUE){

        counter = 0;
    }
```

So, if I want to transmit and visualize on simulink just the actual value of the counter, what I have to write here?

I also implemented these functions in order to use the UART:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{

HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &bufferRX, 1);

}
```

And this is for the printf:

```
int __io_putchar(int ch)
{
/* Place your implementation of fputc here */

/* e.g. write a character to the USART */
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&ch, sizeof(ch), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

/* Loop until the end of transmission */
while (HAL_UART_GetState(&huart2) == HAL_UART_STATE_RESET) {
 }

return ch;
}
```

Comment: printf will ever format into ASCII characters, if you want to transmit in binary just use __io_putchar(counter) instead of printf

Comment: Why use printf isn't the system headless ? printf uses the UART drivers to transmit.

Comment: Side note:  It may work, but don’t recommend function identifiers beginning with a double underscore.  From the standard: All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.